SearchKit searches not displaying after server move
We recently moved all our sites to a new server. When we go to Serach>Searchkit the list headers show but none of the searches under any of the tabs show. Other displays using SearchKit such as Find Contacts, Custom Fields Groups, etc. are working fine. This seems to be the case for all sites we moved. Most are running CiviCRM 5.74.4 but we have a couple still on 5.64.4 with the same issue. All are under WordPress.
I have cleared the cache and emptied the templates_c folder but the issue persists. There searches are fine. I can access them via Form builder and I can create new searches without an issue. Just can't see the list.
Seeing two errors in the console:
crm.ajax.js?r=tHmvLen_US:85  POST https://yoo.kilakwa.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fajax%2Fapi4 404 (Not Found)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'run') at controller.<anonymous> (crmSearchAdminSearchListing.component.js?r=tHmvLen_US:103:27) at searchDisplayBaseTrait.service.js?r=tHmvLen_US:192:22 at qt (lodash.min.js:9:507) at Function.Re (lodash.min.js:37:336) at searchDisplayBaseTrait.service.js?r=tHmvLen_US:191:13 at processQueue (angular.js?r=tHmvLen_US:18075:37) at angular.js?r=tHmvLen_US:18123:27 at Scope.$digest (angular.js?r=tHmvLen_US:19242:15) at angular.js?r=tHmvLen_US:19562:26 at TaskTracker.completeTask (angular.js?r=tHmvLen_US:21403:7) 'Possibly unhandled rejection: {}' (anonymous) @ angular.js?r=tHmvLen_US:15697 Show 1 more frame Show lessUnderstand this error

Did you move the 'ANG' folder to the new server?  That's where the Search Kits are

Yes, the ANG folder was moved. The files are there. The searches are all working and available they just do not appear on the list when I bring it up. Also, this was a complete migration so all the files moved and the paths, etc. did not change.

Sounds like the searchKit listing screen is crashing for some reason. When you load that page please look in your browser console for any error messages.

@Coleman I am seeing two errors. I edited the question and added the errors.

Is https://yoo.kilakwa.com/wp-admin/admin.php a correct and valid url? Does the site you moved to support https?

Yes, that is a valid url and supports SSL. This is a occurring on all Civi sites on the server. I checked a few others and receive similar errors.

Yes, the site support https: and that is a valid url. I checked other sites on the server running Civi and they also get the same error.

Have you checked you have all the PHP requirements ?

We isolated the problem. There was a Mod Security rule in place on the new server that was blocking the action that loads the search lists. We adjusted that rule and it works correctly now.
